# a que se debe este error de json

Tags: javascript, html

SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

segun e leido puede ser que lo que recibe el json no es formato json si no que xml alguien sabe como podria solucionarlo??!

[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbhZY.jpg)

El lugar donde me da error cuando veo en consola es en el resp.json()

okey edite el comentario les agregare la imagen donde devuelvo el json a php
[image: aqui esta]

Comment: Agrega por favor tu código y una muestra de la data que recibes

Comment: Eso significa que el JSON es inválido, porque aparece la etiqueta `< ` junto al eventual JSON. Eso suele ocurrir cuando antes del JSON se imprimen otras cosas, como bloques HTML, XML, mensajes de error, etc. Sin ver el código y el contexto es imposible saber lo que ocurre con exactitud.

Comment: el error lo tenes en la url que devuelve el json, tendrías que compartir la respuesta de ese endpoint para ver que problema tenes en la sintaxis del json

Comment: Me da la impresión de que lo que tienes mal puede ser las comillas del fetch() y las del innerHTML = ...., cámbialas por las que están arriba del todo y prueba

Comment: actualice la pregunta y ahi pongo donde devolvi el json a php pero no se la verdad cual es el problema :'v